# How to access from the list template to the detail template in Django 2?

Tags: django, django-templates, python-3.6, django-2.0

I'm trying to access from the list template, to detail template

Exmaple:

article: urls

```
article_patterns = [
  path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
  path('articles/', ArticleListView.as_view(), name="articles"),
  path('articles/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article"),
]
```

main urls

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', include(article_patterns)),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In `article_list.html`

`<a href="{% url 'articles:article' article.id  %}"> Detail {{articles.title}}</a>`

But I have this error: `articles is not a registered namespace`

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: all your urls.py code please

Comment: Just use `{% url 'article' article.id  %}` without `articles:` namespace.

Comment: Because inside it you have something like app_name

Comment: Thanks @floydya It works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what floydya says and ignore the namespace. But if you want to include it you should add a `namespace` argument to the include function in your main.py.

```
path('', include(article_patterns, namespace="articles"))
```

Edit:

If you want to take this approach and use a `namespace` argument you need to follow the advice given in rawken's answer. That is, set up a urls.py file in your articles app (if there is one) and then include the urls module, not just a list of views. See the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/conf.py)  for the include function if you want to see all of the options.